# Android admob sometimes not displaying

Tags: android, xamarin, admob

I've built a Xamarin Android application containing google admob banners.
Sometimes (maybe only on certain devices but I'm not sure) admob banners are not shown on screen and sometimes, on the same devices, are correctly shown.
What could be the problem?
How can I see admob error log on device to understand the reason?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: You said that the admob banner don't show on some device? Please confirm that you have connect internet in your device firstly.

Comment: Hi Cherry Bu, I think that happens in some devices because I've 2 devices and on one of these (Android 8) banner are shown and in the other device (Android 6) sometimes are shown and sometimes not. In my AdMob statistics, in that last days, about the 10% of admob requests are not confirmed by an impression...and that's strange, never happened in 4 years that my app is online.  The internet connection is active because my app calls an API and data are correctly received. I don't know what to do to solve this

Comment: According to your description, I search some info, but  I am not sure what the problem is, so I suggest you can feedback this issue at github for xamarin, may you can get other info.

Comment: Ok Cherry Bu, thank you for your attempts :)

Comment: I try to test this sample at my side, and the banner display successfylly:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/monodroid-samples/google-services-admobexample/